# Is it possible to pass a route parameter to controller constructor in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection

Is it possible to inject a route-paramter (or an route segment) to the controller-constructor?

You find some code to clarify my question.

```
class TestController{

    protected $_param;

    public function __construct($paramFromRoute)
    {
        $this->param = $paramFromRoute;
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        return "Hello ".$this->_param;
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------

App::bind('TestController', function($app, $paramFromRoute){
    $controller = new TestController($paramFromRoute);
    return $controller;
});

----------------------------------------------------

// here should be some magic
Route::get('foo/{bar}', 'TestController');
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's not possible to inject them, but you have access to all of them via:

```
class TestController{

    protected $_param;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $id = Route::current()->getParameter('id');
    }

}
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

So I could not inject an object with some properties based on the route?

Comment: In Laravel > 5.4 method getParameter() was replaced by parameter(), ref :https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17550

Answer (score 15):

**Laravel 5.3.28**

You can't inject the parameter... 
But, you can inject the request and get it from the router instance, like this:

```
//route: url_to_controller/{param}
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
   $this->param = $request->route()->parameter('param');
}
```

Comment: or simply `$request->param`

Answer (score 5):

In **Laravel 5.4**, you can use this to request the parameter:

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
   $id = $request->get("id");
}
```

Comment: or simply `$request->id`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE FOR LARAVEL 8**

you can use the `route()` method to get the value from the route url parameter from laravel 8:

```php
$id = request()->route('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more testable solution, you can use Service Provider power.

```
        $this->app->bind(TestController::class, function ($app) {
            return new TestController(request()->testParam);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

> Lastly, but most importantly, you may simply "type-hint" the dependency in the constructor of a class that is resolved by the container, including controllers, event listeners, queue jobs, middleware, and more. In practice, this is how most of your objects are resolved by the container.

http://www.golaravel.com/laravel/docs/5.1/container/