# Laravel 5: Call method in class before the method indicated by the route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I'm sure there's a well documented way to do this in Laravel, I'm just missing it or not understanding what I'm reading. I have an application that uses a token for accessing part of the website, rather than a username or password. That token identifies the job, checks the status of the job and then redirects the user to the appropriate page.

This is what I have in my routes.php file so far:

```
$router->pattern('token', '[A-Za-z0-9]{32}');
$router->pattern('id', '[0-9]{1,11}');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{token}', 'middleware' => 'token'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'RedirectController@index');
    Route::get('/first-steps', ['as' => 'firstSteps', 'uses' => 'FirstStepsController@index']);
    Route::get('/first-steps/form', ['as' => 'firstStepsForm', 'uses' => 'FirstStepsController@form']);
    Route::post('/first-steps/form', 'FirstStepsController@processForm');
    Route::get('/designs', ['as' => 'designs', 'uses' => 'DesignsController@index']);
    Route::get('/designs/{id}', ['as' => 'designShow', 'users' => 'DesignsController@show']);
});
```

There are a few other routes that are irrelevant. This all works great, if the user visits the link we give them then `RedirectController@index` checks the stage of the job and redirects them to the correct URL (currently `/first-steps` for stage 1 and `/designs` for stage 2). The problem is if the user bookmarks a page, such as `/first-steps`, when the project moves on to stage 2, the user can still access the stage 1 pages. I want to be able to have a method that runs before the one indicated by the route that makes sure that they are visiting the correct URL for the stage the job is in, redirect if necessary and then store the job (an eloquent object) in the class (or inject it to the method called).

I've tried creating a `before` method in the controller but it doesn't get called:

```
public function before(Request $request, $token)
{
    $this->website = Website::where('access_token', '=', $token)->firstOrFail();
}
```

As you can see in the router I have a custom middleware that validates the token. This is the code for that middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( ! Website::where('access_token', '=', $request->route()->parameter('token'))->count())
    {
        return response('Invalid token.', 401);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I have a feeling that I can use this middleware to achieve what I need to do, but I'm not sure how to proceed or even if I'm on the right track. Can someone please explain what I need to use to achieve my requirements?

Comment: put the token validation in `DesignsController@index` and see if it works or not.

Comment: You should assign the middleware in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`, did you do that?

Comment: @itachi why would I want to move the middle ware into a method? That would mean repeating the middle ware in every single method, which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: @pespantelis yes, the middle ware as it stands now works, it makes sure that the token is valid. I need to take it one step further and validate the page against the stage of the website.

Comment: As per I understand, you need to set a flag in `/first-steps` and then user click back from `/design`  check if flag already set or not, if not than leave them here otherwise redirect to again `/design`. If you unable to understand I will give you small answer.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar, not quite. The page they visit is determined by a pre-existing flag that we change as the project progresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware might be an option.

Alternatively could you do this in the constructor of your BaseController?

E.g.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
         //if token in query string
         //load Job and check status Vs requested URL
         //redirect to correct URL
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you pass the arguments to the class constructor instead on the called method>

Comment: You can't pass a route parameter to the constructor but you can access them. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766894/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-route-parameter-to-controller-constructor-in-laravel

Comment: Do you know how to do this with middleware as you said that might be an option. I guess we could do it with the constructor but that would break the DRY principle.

Comment: It doesn't have to, you only need to implement the check in the constructor of the basecontroller. If your other constructors inherit from it then it will automatically be executed.

Comment: That will work, but you are making mandatory that all of your children controllers need to implement a call to "parent::__construct()" if they use an "__construct()" method. I really don't know if i like this